# How to handle errors using phonegap facebook connect plugin

Tags: android, plugins, error-handling, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using phonegap to develop my app on Android and iOS. So far, I have managed to implement the facebook connect plugin for Android and it works pretty well.

There is one thing I am unable to do, it is how to handle the plugin errors. For instance, when there is no network connection, the FB.login(...) does not work and I got an alert from the facebook-js-sdk.js:
line 5105 :

```
// CORDOVA PATCH
// If the nativeInterface arg is specified then call out to the nativeInterface 
// which uses the native app rather than using the iframe / popup web
if (FB._nativeInterface) {
    switch (params.method) {
        case 'auth.login':
            FB._nativeInterface.login(params, cb, function(e) {alert('Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login!' + e);});
        break;
```

How can I intercept that alert and display my own error? here is the code I am using for the login:

```
login: function(success, error) {
   FB.login(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
        //some code ..
        if (success && typeof(success) === "function") {  
            success();  
        } 
     } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');             
        if (error && typeof(error) === "function") {  
            error(false);  
        } 
     }
   }, {scope: 'email'}); 
}
```

PS: I never enter in the `else` block even if I cancel the login authorization, I've got the same alert.

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem.

Comment: I still have the issue. @EugeneMi if you find something, please share ;)

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems that after the case 'auth.login' it doesnt pass the error back to the app.

Comment: @DmitryIsakov did you try with the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: @icl1c not sure, I`ll check...